# How do I make an event in ROBLOX when a specific dialog?

Tags: dialog, lua, roblox

Say I want to make a brick dissapear when a certain dialog choice is selected.

I make an NPC, then I add a dialog tree. It is now set so when a player talks to the NPC, they have the choice to say "Can you make that brick dissapear?". The NPC replies "There you go!"

What would I need to do to make it so when the NPC replies, the brick dissapears?

Answer (score 4):

On roblox?

There's an event in the Dialog object.

`DialogChoiceSelected(Instance player, Instance dialogChoice)`

This is how you can use it for making a brick "disappear" as long as you have defined the variables "Dialog" and "Brick"

```
Dialog.DialogChoiceSelected:connect(function(Player, Choice)
    if Choice.Name == "BrickChanger" then
        Brick.Transparency = 1
    end
end)
```

The argument "Player" is the player who selected that choice, the "Choice" argument refers to the DialogChoice userdata that was chosen.